# Как получать значения дробного вида из EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Как получать значения дробного вида из EditText? Например, чтобы пользователь вводил дробь 2/3 и она конвертировалась в Double переменную?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2/3 - это по сути математическое выраждение. Чтобы привести его в нормальный вид, нужно рассчитать его значение. Для расчета значения произвольного выражения можно использовать например [JEval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/)

```
        Evaluator evaluator = new Evaluator();

        try {
            String result = evaluator.evaluate("2/3");
        } catch (EvaluationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`evaluator.evaluate` возвращает `String`, который в вашем случае нужно будет привести, например ,к `double`.

Answer (score 0):

1) определяете является ли вводимое строка числом вида a/b, к примеру

```
  // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
  String line = "2/3";
  String pattern = "(\\d+)/(\\d+)";

  // Создаем паттерн
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

 // парсим значении
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Это само строка: " + m.group(0) );
     System.out.println("Это первое число: " + m.group(1) );
     System.out.println("Это второе число: " + m.group(2) );
  } else {
     System.out.println("Нет чисел");
  }
```

2)  если есть значении в `m.group(1)` и `m.group(1)` тогда переводим их в `double` и делим. Получим нужное число

Answer (score 0):

Это задача обычно даётся в университетах, где необходимо написать калькуляторы, можете почитать книгу "Роберт Лафоре - Структуры данных и алгоритмы в Java. 2-е издание", там в конце 4 главы описано подробно, как реализовать подобный алгоритм, для вычисления таких выражений, ибо компьютер не понимает формы записи выражений, как мы, для него необходимо выполнить некоторые преобразования из инфиксного вида в постфиксный, в книги вы всё узнаете, ну а если быстро решение, то есть библиотеки, как было отвечено выше